# сортировка значений внутри group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица

```
user | show
apple | 2017-10-13 23:00:00
peach | 2017-10-13 22:00:00
apple | 2017-10-12 22:00:00
peach | 2017-10-13 21:00:00
```

нужно выбрать user у которого после последнего show прошло больше суток. Запрос написал но он не хочет работать:

```
 SELECT * , max( `show` ) AS `last_show`
    FROM `tbl`
    WHERE `last_show` < NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY `user`
    ORDER BY `last_show` ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

Как отсортировать значение внутри group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения агрегатных функций после группировки можно проверить в предложении `HAVING`, но не в `WHERE` (которое выполняется *до* группировки):

```
  SELECT * , max( `show` ) AS `last_show`
    FROM `tbl`
    GROUP BY `user`
   HAVING max(`show`) < NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ORDER BY `last_show` ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Вроде так:

```
SELECT user, MAX(show) AS last_show
FROM tbl
WHERE user NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT user
                    FROM tbl
                    WHERE show >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                  )
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY last_show
```

Ну или аналогичное с NOT EXISTS и коррелированным подзапросом.